# Run in Conda environment without pip-installed packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm creating a Conda environment and want to make sure it allows anyone to run the scripts in my repository without having to install anything separately. But, I have `pip install`ed some packages on my machine, so, if I understand correctly, some of my imports might work because I pip-installed them and not because they're installed in the Conda environment.

For example, suppose I created an environment with `conda create --name my_env python=3.8.8`. This shouldn't install Pandas, but if I run `import pandas as pd`, it works. I believe this is because I've pip-installed Pandas. My question is:

*How can I test whether a script works with only packages installed in the conda environment?*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a yaml file just from the history of your conda installations:

```
conda env export --from-history --name my_env > myenv.yml
```

From that you create a new conda environment, which you can use to test your script with:

```
conda env create --name conda_only --file myenv.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has flags to ignore PYTHONPATH (`-E`) and default system- or user-level `site-packages` (`-S`), as well as a combined flag (`-I`) that does both (see `python -h`). Try using such flags to isolate from the system. Something like,

```bash
conda run -n my_env python -I script.py
```

Also, it should be clarified that `pip install` is only an issue like this if you are using the `--user` flag, which triggers a user-level installation of packages, or some alternate location (e.g., `--root` or `--prefix` flags) and have PYTHONPATH set to make those accessible.